# How to add bootstrap 4 datepicker in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, bootstrap-4

I have been trying to add bootstrap 4 datepicker from this [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2019/01/03/how-to-use-date-picker-with-django.html). It works great when I add a new record but problem is when editing the record, the value has not appeared in the field. What I have done is:

**widgets.py**

```
from django.forms import DateTimeInput, DateInput

class BootstrapDateTimePickerInput(DateTimeInput):
    template_name = 'widgets/bootstrap_datetimepicker.html'

    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs):
        datetimepicker_id = 'datetimepicker_{name}'.format(name=name)
        if attrs is None:
            attrs = dict()
        attrs['data-target'] = '#{id}'.format(id=datetimepicker_id)
        attrs['class'] = 'form-control datetimepicker-input'
        context = super().get_context(name, value, attrs)
        context['widget']['datetimepicker_id'] = datetimepicker_id
        return context
```

**forms.py**

```
class ClaimForm(forms.ModelForm):

    purchase_date = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'], widget=BootstrapDateTimePickerInput())

    class Meta(forms.ModelForm):
        model = Claim
        fields = ['store', 'expense', 'rewards', 'money_receipt', 'purchase_date']
```

I want to add the date value into the input field when I edit the form.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

We have built a Django Python package for Bootstrap 4 date and time picker widgets on top of the Tempus Dominus JS library. Details are here:

https://pypi.org/project/django-tempus-dominus/

For your case, something like this would work:

```
from tempus_dominus.widgets import DateTimePicker

purchase_date = forms.DateTimeField(
    widget=DateTimePicker(),
    initial='1980-01-01 12:00:00',
)
```

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I have just installed it now. it works but my problem is not fixed that is when I edit the form, the existing value has not appeared in the field

Comment: In the form field, you'll have to pass the existing value from the model as `initial`. I'll amend my answer.